# How to redirect user depending on user type at time of login (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm facing problem while redirecting my user according to its type. how can do it here's my code please suggest how to do it.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index()
  {
       $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);

    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password'
      'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {        

     //Field validation failed.&nbsp; User redirected to login page
     validation_errors();

     $this->load->view('error');
  }
 else
  {
  //Go to private area
```

basically here I want to redirect if user is admin then redirect to admin page else redirect to home. How can I do this ???

```
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
     }
    }


   function check_database($password)
   {
    //Field validation succeeded.&nbsp; Validate against database
      $username = $this->input->post('username');

       //query the database
       $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

     if($result)
     {
      $sess_array = array();
       foreach($result as $row)
      {
       $sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
     );
     $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

        }
        return TRUE;
      }
    else
       {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
         return false;
       }
     }  
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: if you assist or provide a code , it would be very helpful

Comment: Where is the actual login code and do you have user type in the database?

Comment: @RickCalder yes i have usergropu table in my database and its foreign key lies in my account table. here is my code for login function

Comment: Class User extends CI_Model  {function login($username, $password)
        {
            $this->db->select('username,password');
            $this->db->from('account') ;
            $this->db->where('username = ' . "'" . $username . "'");
            $this->db->where('password = ' . "'" . $password . "'");
            $this->db->limit(1);
            
            $query= $this->db-> get();
            if($query->num_rows()==1) {return $query->result();} else {return false;}

Comment: There is no login code there, you're calling a login function but no code for it. $result = $this->user->login($username, $password); won't actually do anything on it's own.

Comment: i don't why code is not pasting correctly here right now ..sorry for inconvenience , well this is login function . and it works well

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is by joining the user with a roles table. Each user is assigned to a role (such as salesperson, accounting manager, etc.). Each role has an *optional* home page to redirect to after login. If it's not set, it redirects to a default page.

Comment: yes , im doing it the same . my account table contains foreign key of usergroup table . but i want to know that how to write the code and where ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well you say you have a login function so here are the basics. What Mike is saying is right and how I do it, but if you only have two types of users a roles solution is probably overkill. Personally I use the roles to populate a user menu, all users get the same menu, the options change depending on what portions of the site they're allowed to see.

For a basic admin/user though that's really not necessary. What you need to do is just redirect based on usergroup after login, so something similar to this.

```
$this->db->where(username, $username);
$this->db->where(password, $password);
$query = $this->db->get(users);
if($query->num_results() ==1)
{
    $result = $query->result_array();
    switch ($result['usergroup']) {
        case '1':
        redirect 'home';
        break;
        case '2':
        redirect 'admin';
        break;
        default:
        redirect 'home';
        break;
    }
}
```

As I said this is a basic solution that you can use for a few different roles, if you want to do anything more complicated investigate creating roles.

You'll also want to save the usergroup to the session and check it on admin pages, if the user isn't an admin redirect them away from the page.

Comment: this looks quite easy but if you tell me

Comment: Tell you what? I gave you the code, just adapt it to your login.

Comment: this looks quite easy but if you tell me few things as i'm new to codeignitor.                                                       1)   switch ($result['usergroup'])   am i supposed to pass table name in result array ? as my table name is account at its attribute is usergroup_FK . if value in usergroup_FK is 1 then its ordinary user if its 2 then its admin .                                     2) if u look above at my first code where i am redirecting to home page , i think it would be redundant as im redirecting twice then , if i do as you said !!  so plz elaborate

Comment: Add the account table to the query in the model, then return that value with the others to the controller, move the switch statement to the controller. The code I supplied was just an example of how it works.